# Can't insert data to database on form submit

Tags: database, forms

I am trying to insert some datas into database table on form submit like this:

```
function form_example_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    if ($form_state['values']['select']=='1') $gender = 'male';
    else $gender = 'female';

    db_insert('form_example_table')->fields(array(
      'name'    => $form_state['values']['name'],
      'gender'  => $gender,
      'message' => $form_state['values']['message'],      

    ))->execute();

    drupal_set_message("Message is successfully saved"); 

    return $form;

}
```

My schema in .install file looks like this:

```
function form_example_schema() {

    $schema['form_example_table'] = array(
        'description' => 'Table for form_pokus module',
        'fields' => array(
            'id'        => array('type' => 'serial', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE),
            'name'      => array('type' => 'varchar','length' => 30,     'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => ''),
            'gender'    => array('type' => 'varchar','length' => 30,     'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => ''),
            'message'   => array('type' => 'text', 'not null' => TRUE,   'default'  => ''),
            'status'    => array('type' => 'text', 'not null' => FALSE ),
            'created'   => array('type' => 'int',  'not null' => TRUE,   'default'  => 0),          
        ),

        'primary key' => array('id'),

    );

    return $schema;
}
```

But nothing happens on form submit, only page is reloaded. What I am mising?

Comment: Do you see the message "Message is successfully saved"? If not, your submit function isn't running

Comment: No, but I see the message now after you indirectly suggested where error could be and after renaming 'form_example_submit' to 'form_example_form_submit'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your schema

```
<?php
function form_example_schema() {

    $schema['form_example_table'] = array(
        'description' => 'Table for form_pokus module',
        'fields' => array(
            'id'        => array('type' => 'serial', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE),
            'name'      => array('type' => 'varchar','length' => 30,     'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => ''),
            'gender'    => array('type' => 'varchar','length' => 30,     'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => ''),
            'message'   => array('type' => 'text', 'not null' => TRUE,   'default'  => ''),
            'status'    => array('type' => 'text', 'not null' => FALSE ),
            'created'   => array('type' => 'int',  'not null' => TRUE,   'default'  => 0),          
        ),

        'primary key' => array('id'),

    );

    return $schema;
}
?>
```

needs to look like:

```
function form_example_schema() {

    $schema['form_pokus_table'] = array(
        'description' => 'Table for form_pokus module',
        'fields' => array(
            'id'        => array('type' => 'serial', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE),
            'name'      => array('type' => 'varchar','length' => 30,     'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => ''),
            'gender'    => array('type' => 'varchar','length' => 30,     'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => ''),
            'message'   => array('type' => 'text', 'not null' => TRUE,   'default'  => ''),
            'status'    => array('type' => 'text', 'not null' => FALSE ),
            'created'   => array('type' => 'int',  'not null' => TRUE,   'default'  => 0),          
        ),

        'primary key' => array('id'),

    );

    return $schema;
}
```

you had the wrong table name as the schema index.

Comment: I have 'pokus' word everywhere instead of 'example' , but I renamed it here on stackexchange because it is foreign language word and forgot to rename this one. Problem must be somewhere  else.

Comment: OP is using `db_insert('form_example_table')`, so the table name is already correct

Comment: oh there was a previous revision, my bad

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the proper hook name is not `form_example_submit` but `form_example_form_submit`.